# CSS-Javascript: Show and Hide div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a menu where there is just title and a view more link is provided. 
If that link is clicked it should open a hidden div and that view more should change to show less or close. And if I click that the div should close again.
So far I have this.

```
Title 1 <a href="#" onclick="showdiv()">View More</a>
<div id="title1_div">
Some Information
</div>

<style>
#title1_div{
display:none;
}
</style>

<script>
function showdiv()
{
document.getElementById('title1_div').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

This only provides the on click show division. How can I close that div on clicking.

Any help would be appreciated.

Please see this example at JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eo4cysec/

Comment: You do the opposite of what you did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just check if the property is set to block, if so you set it to none, else you set it to block. So you have a toggling logic in it.

```
if(document.getElementById('title1').style.display == 'block') {
   document.getElementById('title1').style.display = 'none';
} else {
   document.getElementById('title1').style.display = 'block';
}
```

To set the text to **View Less** you need the reference of the clicked tag, you pass it as parameter like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showdiv(this)">View More</a>
```

Then you have the chance to use this parameter and set the `innerHTML` of it, which is the text that is displayed. So the final function will look like this, where `e` is now the reference on the `a`-tag:

```
function showdiv(e) {
  if(document.getElementById('title1').style.display == 'block') {
     e.innerHTML = 'View More';
     document.getElementById('title1').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
     e.innerHTML = 'View Less';
     document.getElementById('title1').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Please check out this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/g7ry88h7/

Comment: Missed to change the anchor's text from "View More" to "Show Less" or "Close".

Answer (score 1):

Simple function. Call it on click and it'll handle the hide/show:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Missed to change the anchor's text from "View More" to "Show Less" or "Close".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example.

```js
function showdiv(el) {
  if (el.innerHTML == "View More") {
    document.getElementById('title1').style.display = 'block';
    el.innerHTML = "Show Less";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('title1').style.display = 'none';
    el.innerHTML = "View More";
  }
}
```

```css
#title1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Title 1
<div id="title1">
  Some Information
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="showdiv(this)">View More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function () {  
  $(this).next('div').stop(true, true).slideToggle("fast");

if($(this).html() == 'View More'){
       $(this).html('View Less');
   } else {
       $(this).html('View More');
   }
}),
```

Comment: I don't think he's using jQuery, so... there's also no jQuery in the tags.

Comment: It's good to see your answer. Maybe mention that "A solution using jQuery", OP haven't included jQuery tag.

Comment: Sorry, yes I should have mentioned this is a jQuery solution.